# Identify Return Key action in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a `TextInput` which I have enabled `multiline` as true. Thing is the Keyboard won't hide after Return is pressed. It goes to a new line. So I was hoping to use [react-native-dismiss-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dismiss-keyboard). To exploit this I need to identify the Return key action. How to do this?

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.additionalTextInput}
    multiline={true}
    autoCapitalize="sentences"
    autoCorrect={true}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    keyboardType="default"
    returnKeyType="done"
    onKeyPress={(keyPress) => console.log(keyPress)}
    placeholder="Enter text here..."
/>
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

What I used is `onSubmitEditing` props. e.g.

```
<TextInput style={[styles.textInput]}
  placeholder='搜索'
  placeholderTextColor='#bbb'
  onChange={(event) => {
    this.searchChange(event.nativeEvent.text)
  }}
  returnKeyType='search'
  autoFocus={true}
  value={ this.props.searchName }
  selectionColor={colors.orangeColor}
  onSubmitEditing={this.searchSubmit}
  clearButtonMode="while-editing"
/>
```

Answer (score 35):

Okay, found the solution.

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.additionalTextInput}
    multiline={true}
    autoCapitalize="sentences"
    autoCorrect={true}
    onChangeText={(orderInstructions) => this.setState({orderInstructions})}
    keyboardType="default"
    returnKeyType="done"
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
    placeholder="Enter text here..."
/>

handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    if(e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        dismissKeyboard();
    }
},
```

The method dismissKeyboard is from [react-native-dismiss-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dismiss-keyboard).

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: If you grab the reference, you can also just run a blur on it: `this._textInput.blur(); // dismiss keyboard`

Comment: onKeyPress is iOS only, what about android?

Comment: You can `import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'` and call `Keyboard.dismiss()`. Just my 2 cents, so you dont really need `react-native-dismiss-keyboard.`.

Comment: @RainerLiao Not the case anymore: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/14720

Comment: I tried this, but handleKeyDown never occurred when return was pressed

Comment: @WalterMonecke Your advice works, however, one can see the return in the field (it can be removed from the state variable, for a controlled input, but the return is still seen for a short time). Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @NimilaHiranya I am using Keyboard.dismiss() instead of the dismissKeyboard() (Walter's advice). When I do this in a field with multiline set to true (same as your example), the keyboard is dismissed, but the <Return> is displayed in the field. I remove it in my onChangeText() handler (it is a controlled input field), but it is still visible for a fraction of a second. Does this happen to you, too?

Answer (score 23):

In case you are using with `multiline={true}`, the `return` key would also add the newline in the text before calling `onSubmitEditing`. Also, the keyboard won't get dismissed automatically making you `import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'` and calling `Keyboard.dismiss()` in onSubmitEditing.

An easier solution would be to use the `blurOnSubmit={true}` to automatically dismiss the keyboard and prevent `return` key from registering as `newline`.

Comment: This solution actually works best when multiline=true

Comment: Works perfectly with `multiline` !!

Comment: This is the simplest answer.