# React Native: e.nativeEvent.key == 'Enter' doesn't work

Tags: react-native, textinput

this question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764782/identify-return-key-action-in-react-native), however, for some reason every key tends to work except the return key (Enter key). what i want is to proceed the user to the next page if password is correct. any help would be really appreciated

//Code

```
        <TextInput
                style={styles.txtfield}
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor = 'rgba(249, 129, 37, 1)'
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onChangeText={ password => this.setState({ password })}
                keyboardType="default"
                returnKeyType="next"                        
                onKeyPress={ (event) => {
                    if(event.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
                        alert(event.nativeEvent.key) // doesn't output anything nor execute the signin function
                        // this.signIn();
                    } 
                    else {
                        alert('Something else Pressed') // show a valid alert with the key info
                    }
                }}
            />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you will get the `onPress` event for **Enter** key only if there is `multiline` `TextInput`.

For single line `TextInput`, you will get 'Enter' or 'Submit' keypress event in the `onSubmitEditing` method.

```
  <TextInput
            style={styles.txtfield}
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor = 'rgba(249, 129, 37, 1)'
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={ password => this.setState({ password })}
            keyboardType="default"
            returnKeyType="next"
            onSubmitEditing={()=>{
                alert('on submit') // called only when multiline is false
            }}                        
            onKeyPress={ (event) => {
                if(event.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
                    alert(event.nativeEvent.key) //called when multiline is true
                    // this.signIn();
                } 
                else {
                    alert('Something else Pressed') 
                }
            }}
        />
```